# Conditions required to take derivative out of integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, reference-request

What are the requirements (or related Theorem) necessary for the a derivative of a function of two variables to be taken out of the integral, for example: $$\int \frac{d}{dt}\vec{B} \cdot d \vec{a} = \frac{d}{dt} \int \vec{B} \cdot d \vec{a}$$ where $\vec{B}$ is a function of area and time and $d \vec{a}$ is the differential of area only. So I guess generally when is is possible to have $$\int g(f(x,t))dx = g(\int f(x,t) dx)$$ where $g$ is a function of $t$ only.

Thanks.

Comment: Your final condition requires some special properties on $g$... I would be surprised if there are any non-trivial, easy to construct functions $g$ except for the derivative... But I would love to be wrong! Also, for the case where it's a derivative is known as "Leibez's Integral Rule" if I remember correctly. I'll grab a link in just a sec

Comment: Here's a [link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)